# Firefox addon for GMailing an image found on the web

Tags: firefox, gmail, browser-addons

Is there a firefox add on somewhere out there that enables you to attach a file (it would be preferable if it worked as a general case, enabling all kinds of files) with a new gmail message and email it.

Example: I found an image on the net which I wish to mail to someone. Without downloading it to my hdd, and ... I just press for example the right button, "gmail this", and a new gmail compose window opens up, I add some text, and away it goes.

Anyone knows of such a add on ?

It seems like a relatively obvious thing, but still, haven't been able to find it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[**Send Page By Email**](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/2343) does this.

> Send webpage, send text, and send
>   image on the webpage you are currently
>   browsing in Firefox directly by email
>   to anyone you want. It can also send
>   user defined messages along.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The [Ubiquity](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/9527) addon can be used to email a page. With a bit of practice, or maybe in future versions, it could probably email a specific element of a page.

Answer (score 0):

If you can select the graphic, it is possible copy and paste it from the webpage into a GMail message.

That's the fastest way I have found to do it.

Comment: That works for images which the browser can show. But for some, he instantly chooses download (still a little confused why he does that), so then I have to download those ... etc, etc...